# How to implement and use NETXMS Custom SNMP Network Device Driver?

Tags: c++, driver, monitoring, snmp, mib

I have MIB files for my network device and I want to build a custom NETXMS device driver, I have read that we can build it in c++, but I didn't find how.

I searched for the files of the standard drivers which are already installed with NETXMS server, I found files in ( C:\NetXMS\lib\ndd ) folder with extension (.ndd) (I can't understand them), what is this extension? and in which extension (or how?) should I export my driver to import it and use it in the server?

Answer (score 0):

For most devices you don't need custom driver, GENERIC works just fine. Purpose of the device drivers is to work around some quirks with specific hardware (like physical ports layout on the switch) or firmware versions.

You don't even need MIBs to collect data from the device (just put correct OID when setting up DCI), but it's definitely helps when you can see them in MIB browser.

To add custom MIBs:

1. Copy new MIB files to C:\NetXMS\share\mibs (make sure that file extension is .txt)
2. run "C:\NetXMS\bin\nxmibc.exe -z -d C:\NetXMS\share\mibs -o C:\NetXMS\var\mibs\netxms.mib" (I recommend to do it from cmd prompt, this way you'll see if there are any errors)
3. Restart management console (there are no need to restart server)

However, if you need to implement custom driver, I suggest to use existing code as a reference: https://github.com/netxms/netxms/tree/master/src/server/drivers. Driver is a shared library (e.g. dll on windows) which is loaded by the server on startup.

Comment: I tried to build the driver "net-snmp", but there is error in:
#include <netxms-build-tag.h>